# Spring properties inside library

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

So I've got a library which contains default things like authentication and stuff like that, which are all equal across multiple applications.

I'd like to have an application.properties inside the library setting up some default values. But at the same time I would like the actual application to be able to overwrite these library values inside the applications' properties file.

But I can't seem to figure out how to get spring to read the librarys' property file.

Comment: Can you tell the directory structure, what kind of library is it, is it a spring project data library? which is imported in web on project?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'data library'. But to give context, I have Spring Boot RestAPI applications, which are supposed to import said lib so the general setup of each application is the same

Comment: what kind of library it is and what are the properties you wish to override?